# How to find new questions

Tags: support

I'm sorry if I'm asking a silly question and the answer should be obvious but when I visit Workplace, no matter which tab is selected, I mostly see questions with several answers already in place. Every once in a while I see questions with no answers but only rarely. SE used to have a listing for new questions (that were just recently asked) but I don't think I see those anymore (the tabs all just show questions with high activity, regardless of age).

Am I doing something wrong? Or are newly asked questions simply at the end of the active queue?

Here's a screenshot from a few minutes ago:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the update on responsive design and left navigation sidebar, the navigation bar is moved from the header of the site to the left sidebar.

If the user is enabling [hide left navigation](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) (based on the screenshot), the left navigation will be collapsed into the hamburger menu on the top-left (beside Stack Exchange logo).

You can access the "all questions" list from there, or accessing [this direct link](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) for the newest questions.

Comment: Ah, right, since I never look at that menu, I forgot about it. Thank you.